# Auto-instrument a Sanic Application?

Tags: python, dockerfile, instrumentation, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I want to auto-instrument a Sanic python application. I'm running the application on docker services and using the pods hostIp as an endpoint for otel-collector. This endpoint is created once the pod is up after deployment and the hostIp is not available while deploying the application. Because of this I've to run a manual instrumentation to add **with** spans across all functions, which is not the best approach because of the large code base

Sample Code

```
provider = TracerProvider(resource=Resource(attributes={"service.name": "app_name","env": os.getenv("ENV", "dev")}))
collector_endpoint = f'http://{os.environ.get("NODE_IP")}:{os.environ.get("OTEL_PORT")}'
processor = BatchSpanProcessor(OTLPSpanExporter(endpoint=collector_endpoint))
provider.add_span_processor(processor)

# Sets the global default tracer provider
trace.set_tracer_provider(provider)

# Creates a tracer from the global tracer provider
tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)


# Function 1
def database_fetch_operation(self, query, values=(), commit=False):
    with tracer.start_as_current_span("database_fetch_operation") as span:
        span.set_attribute("database_fetch_operation.query.value", query)
        fetch_result = None

# Function 2
def check_centre_exists(table_name, data):
    with tracer.start_as_current_span("check_centre_exists_faas") as span:
        span.set_attribute("check_centre_exists_faas.data.title", data.get('title'))
        facility_type = data.get('title')
```

I want to auto-instrument Sanic Apps, to avoid adding decorators or **with** spans across every funciton